# How To print out some data from a select query using PHP

Tags: php, html

This is my code:

```
$arr = array(
    'cust_id' => "{$_SESSION['cust_id']}"
);

$query = $sql->select_query("code",$arr);
$result = $mysqli->query($query);

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<option name='{$row['pagename']}>{echo $row['pagename']}</option>";

?>
```

All I need to do is print out a option for each `pagename` for use in a drop down menu. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                              echo "<option name='{$row['pagename']}>{echo $row['pagename']}</option>";
```

to

```
<?php
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
?>
     <option name="<?php echo $row['pagename']; ?>" > <?php echo $row['pagename']; ?> </option>
<?php
} ?>
```